# How do I get/delete every bot's guild's command? (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I tried searching from `client.guild[put_any_index_that_exists_here][1]` object to find commands/command object
I also tried googling it and no good resoults for Discord.js.

What im trying to atchieve is deleting every single bot's(my bot's) command
in every single server it is in and re-adding them back.
^
|
In other words Refresh guild commands list.

Code so far:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, IntentsBitField, REST, Routes, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
      IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
      IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
      IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
      IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
  ]
})

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'get',
    description: 'gets message',
  },
];

// const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Registering slash commands...');
    const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);
    await client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
    for(guild of client.guilds.cache){
      console.log(`removing cmds from guildID: ${await guild[0]}`)
      console.log(guild[1].commands.permissions.guild)
    }
    for (guild of client.guilds.cache) {
      console.log(`added commands to server guildID: ${guild[0]}`)
      await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationGuildCommands(
          process.env.CLIENT_ID,
          guild[0]
        ),
        { body: commands }
      );
    }

    console.log('Slash commands were registered successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`There was an error: ${error}`);
  }
})();
```

What did you try and what were you expecting?
Describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually resulted. Minimum 20 characters.

- As I said I tried searching for commands object inside client.guilds[guildindex][1] and then googling.

And discord.js documentation is outdated (or seems to be) and no good resoults.

Answer (score 0):

First off, that is not how you search for guild commands. Guilds cannot be indexed anyhow.

To get commands:

- #### fetch commands by name:

```js
const command = client.application.commands.cache.find((c) => c.name === 'ping');
console.log(command);
```

- #### fetch commands by id:

```js
const command = client.application.commands.cache.get('id');
```

Make sure to fetch commands before!

#### Removing guild commands

- Using [GuildApplicationCommandManager#delete](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildApplicationCommandManager?scrollTo=delete)

```js
await guild.commands.fetch(); // caching all the commands.
guild.commands.cache.forEach((command) => {
    guild.commands.delete(command.id);
});
```

#### Registering guild command(s)

- Using [GuildApplicationCommandManager#create](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildApplicationCommandManager?scrollTo=create)

```js
guild.commands.create({
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'replies with pong!'
});
```

However, I do not suggest using these methods. Instead, use [REST](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/rest/main/general/welcome) & [Routes](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10#Routes):

#### Registering commands

```js
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken('token');

const commands = []; // fetch commands somehow, using `fs`, etc.

try {
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands('clientId', 'guildId'), {
        body: commands;
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

#### Deleting commands

```js
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken('token');

try {
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands('clientId', 'guildId'), {
        body: []; // an empty array indicates no commands
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Reference: [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/), [discord.js](https://old.discordjs.dev/), [discord-api-types](https://discord-api-types.dev/)